# Align Column to Bottom Center in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

So I've just started using Jetpack Compose so everything is pretty new to me.
However I saw on some post that in order to put a column on the bottom of the screen I could use: `.weight(1f)` or `.align(Alignment.BottomCenter)`. However neither of these seem to work.

I get this message in the import (.weight):

```
`Cannot access 'ColumnScopeInstance': it is internal in 'androidx.compose.foundation.layout`
```

And this message on (.align):

```
Cannot access 'BoxScopeInstance': it is internal in 'androidx.compose.foundation.layout'
```

How my code currently looks:

```
@Composable
fun SpeedBar() {
    Column(
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        modifier = Modifier
            .clip(RoundedCornerShape(topStart = 16.dp, topEnd = 16.dp))
            .background(mycolor)
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .weight(1f) // This doesn't work
            .align(Alignment.BottomCenter) // This also doesn't work
            .padding(15.dp)
    ) {
        Image(
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.button_image),
            contentDescription = "Button1",
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(width = 150.dp, height = 150.dp)
                .clip(RoundedCornerShape(16.dp))
                .clickable {

                }
        )

        Button(
            colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(Color.Green),
            onClick = { /*TODO*/ },
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(8.dp)
        ) {
            Text(
                text = "Placeholder",
                color = Color.White,
                fontSize = 24.sp
            )
        }
    }
}
```

The import Android Studio gives me:

```
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.ColumnScopeInstance.weight
```

Comment: You can't use align modifier in an element without it being inside of a Box. So you have to wrap your column with a Box

Answer (score 2):

As @ayman-ait mentioned, you can't use align modifier without keeping the element in a Box. You can do something like this:

Create a Box with max size and put the column in it.

```
Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
    // add your column here (with align modifier)
    Column(modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.BottomCenter)) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah thanks, I figured this out too. Compose is a learning curve coming from xml :)